# Angle between 2 vectors in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

I was effectuating exercise #40 of chapter 1 in Schaum's outlines on Complex Variables. The question asks for the acute angle between $z_1=3-4i$ and $z_2=-4+3i$. Then using the definition
$$\cos \theta={z_1 \circ z_2 \over \left|z_1\right| \left|z_2\right|}=-24/25=-.96$$
But then the author takes the angle as

> $\cos^{-1}.96=16^\circ 16'$ approximately.

However, using the arccosine identity, $\cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cos^{-1}x$. Besides, if we draw the actual vectors, we see that the vectors lie on opposite quadrants of the plane, which confirms this.

Therefore I ask, is there a different meaning in $\mathbb{C}$ for the angle between vectors than in high school trigonometry? Was the author justified in their actions in this example?

Also, how are angles between vectors generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a geometric meaning behind it? From what I've learned, the definition is the same in linear algebra, but I don't know what it actually represents.

Comment: This whole question is confusing. Given your definitions of $z_1,z_2$, $z_1\cdot z_2$ is a complex number. Did you mean $z_1=(3,-4)$ and $z_2=(-4,3)$? And are you sure you didn't make any typos ?

Comment: You are right: that angle is about $163.74^\circ$.

Comment: In the book, for 2 complex numbers $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$, the author defines the dot product as $z_1 \circ z_2=x_1 \cdot x_2+y_1 \cdot y_2$.

I changed the symbol to a circle to distinguish it from regular multiplication.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I know that there are issues with multi-valued functions, branch cuts, and what-not in $\mathbb{C}$... could you explain how it affects the definition of an angle because of $\cos^{-1}$ branch cuts in this case? Are there many cases that are different from usual trigonometry?

Comment: @K.defaoite, far as I know complex numbers are equivalent with $\Bbb R^2$ vectors.

Comment: @WindSoul Isomorphic is not the same thing as equivalent.

Comment: The arccosine is only being taken of real values, not complex, so there is no worries about  
 "branch cuts". Real values in, real values out. Just because the real numbers you are using themselves come from a calculation involving complex numbers does not mean you are taking the arccosine of something complex.

Comment: Because the author uses degrees and minutes to measure angles between complex numbers, and the fact that they call talk about the "acute angle" between two vectors that clearly meet in an obtuse angle, I have to assume this is a very old text. No one uses degree to measure angles in higher mathematics anymore. And we might talk about the acute angle between the *lines* through $0$ and the two vectors, but not of the vectors themselves. "Acute" means $<\frac\pi 2$ and "obtuse" means $>\frac\pi 2$, and are only used of traditional angles (between $0$ and $\pi$).

Comment: But I think WindSoul was right in the now-deleted answer. The author meant the acute angle between the two lines. So while $\arccos(-.96) = 163^\circ42'$, the acute angle between the lines is the supplementary angle $\arccos(.96) = 16^\circ16'$. As for your question about $\Bbb R^n$, note that no matter how many dimensions are around, angles are defined between intersecting lines, and two intersecting lines *always* lie in a plane, where the concept has exactly the same geometric meaning you already know.